# No sound while running Chasm: The Rift on DOSBox

Tags: audio-hardware, windows-xp, dosbox, dos, chasm-the-rift

I recently retrieved my copy of *Chasm: The Rift* from my really old Windows 95 laptop, and I'm trying to run it on Windows XP via DOSBox. However, there is no sound, even though the game is supposed to be fully supported.

The sound works perfectly when I run it on Windows XP as is, but the game crashes when it tries to load a level.

From what I've read, *Chasm* is supposed to automatically pick up the sound configuration. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Odd, the sound works when I reset the game to default settings. Apparently the game somehow thought it was running on the old computer.

I'm leaving this question up in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

Comment: You should submit that as the answer. You're allowed to self-answer here.